# When to initialize resources to be used inside Compose Canvas?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Jetpack Compose and I want to create a circle with custom shadow/gradient effects. As far as I know there is no way to create that with composable objects inside `DrawScope` and I have to use `NativeCanvas` instead. That works fine for my case, but as I remember when we use View and we write something in the `onDraw()` method, we SHOULD NOT INITIALIZE NEW OBJECTS there. Since the method is called on each 30/60fps when using animation and creating new objects for each call will lead to poor performance.

Where is the proper place to define those object `BlurMaskFilter`, `RadialGradient`, `Paint` so they could be re-initialized only when the size of the composable is changes?
I was wondering if I should define them as `lateinit var` outside the function and then use `SideEffect`, to initialize them?
I forgot to mention that I am using `InfiniteTransition`, and then using the state to change shapes that are drawn inside the `NativeCanvas`!

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(widthDp, widthDp)
        .drawBehind {

            drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
                canvas.nativeCanvas.apply {
                    
                    val blurMask = BlurMaskFilter(
                        15f,
                        BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL
                    )
                    val radialGradient = android.graphics.RadialGradient(
                        100f, 100f, 50f,
                        intArrayOf(android.graphics.Color.WHITE, android.graphics.Color.BLACK),
                        floatArrayOf(0f, 0.9f), android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
                    )
                    val paint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
                        shader = radialGradient
                        maskFilter = blurMask
                        color = android.graphics.Color.WHITE
                    } 
                    drawCircle(100f, 100f, 50f, paint)
                }
            }
        }
) {

}
```

Comment: I would say that it should not redraw unless the canvas size or one of the state variables is changed, try adding some logs to check this.

Comment: I am using InfiniteTransition, and then using the state to change shapes that are drawn inside the NativeCanvas, so the draw method is frequently called. But where should I create the gradient and shadow objects, so I can reuse them?

Comment: do these values depend on the transition value or are they fixed?

Comment: I was building a clock, where all 3 arrows for hour, minutes, and seconds were rotated on each available frame using InfiniteTransition. But since drawIntoCanvas is being called on each available frame, if I put the initialization blurMask  and radialGradient in the drawing scope this will happen each time. But the blurMask  and radialGradient are not depending on any transition value, they should be updated only when the size of the composable is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to keep some objects between recompositions in Compose - using `remember` or representation models. For this particular case `remember` is a better fit.

If you have a static size given by `Modifier.size(widthDp, widthDp)`, it is easy to calculate everything in advance:

```
val density = LocalDensity.current
val paint = remember(widthDp) {
    // in case you need to use width in your calculations
    val widthPx = with(density) {
        widthDp.toPx()
    }
    val blurMask = BlurMaskFilter(
        15f,
        BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL
    )
    val radialGradient = android.graphics.RadialGradient(
        100f, 100f, 50f,
        intArrayOf(android.graphics.Color.WHITE, android.graphics.Color.BLACK),
        floatArrayOf(0f, 0.9f), android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
    )
    Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
        shader = radialGradient
        maskFilter = blurMask
        color = android.graphics.Color.WHITE
    }
}
```

If you don't have a static size, for example you want to use `Modifier.fillMaxSize`, you can use `Modifier.onSizeChanged` to get the real size and update your `Paint` - that's why I pass `size` as `key` in the `remember` call - it will recalculate the value when the `key` changes.

```
val (size, updateSize) = remember { mutableStateOf<IntSize?>(null) }
val paint = remember(size) {
    if (size == null) {
        Paint()
    } else {
        Paint().apply { 
            // your code
        }
    }
}
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .onSizeChanged(updateSize)
        .drawBehind {
           // ...
        }
)
```

Comment: If for example I need to draw 2 different circles one of them is using RadialGradient and the other one LinearGradient. Is it ok to use remember for each gradient and then reuse my Paint object?
val linearGradient = remember(widthDp) { android.graphics.LinearGradient(....)}
val radialGradient = remember(widthDp) { android.graphics.RadialGradient(....)}

Comment: @slaviboy sure, you can use these same as plain variables.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is correct, there is a much nicer approach.
Just use modifier drawWithCache. In your case:

```
Modifier
  .drawWithCache {
    // setup calculations and paints
    
    onDrawBehind {
       // draw
    }
  }
```

Don't forget to read the documentation of the drawWithCache to be sure your code matches the conditions to reuse the cache (seems like it does).